# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio unable to connect to Server

Tags: sql-server

I freshly installed Microsoft SQL Server on my machine and started it. When I try to connect to a server I use a `.` for the server name (which should point to the local machine from what I read?). However I get the following error:

[image]

So I went to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and checked under SQL Server Services, which seems to be empty.

[image]

How can I establish a connection?

Comment: Connection to what? Doesn't look like the engine was installed.

Comment: Install the engine, IIRC it's called `Local DB` in the install options.

Comment: If you install **just** the management GUI - there's no **SQL Server engine** to connect to! You also need to install at least one **SQL Server engine!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your services are not running.**

Make sure you installed this.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 0):

**The above answer was correct, however, you only installed the SQL Server Management Studio.**

If you installed Express, downloaded from the Microsoft website you might want to download and create the server instance with the management studio. You will need to select if you want Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication using a username and password. Remember to add the current windows user for using either.

Here is SQL Server 2014 Express: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx.
This will download everything you need to connect to a server.

Please let me know if you need more information.